# Cloudflare caching resources for which cookie is set

Tags: caching, nginx, cookies, http-headers, cloudflare

I'm setting some cookies and appropriate cache-headers (to not cache) while responding a requested .gif file. According to Cloudflare documentation:

> If the Cache-Control header is set to "private", "no-store", "no-cache",  or "max-age=0", or if there is a cookie in the response, then Cloudflare will not cache the resource.

I know that there's a default caching of .gif files but I can see 'CF-Cache-Status:MISS' in response-header. So, the issue is not caching but that the cookie is not being forwarded to client from my backend server.

Response Header sent by my backend server:

> Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>
> Content-Type:image/gif
>
> Content-Length:12345
>
> Date:Wed, 12 Jul 2017 13:50:29 GMT
>
> Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> **Set-Cookie:user=randomuser; Max-Age=7776000; Expires=Tue, 10-Oct-2017 13:38:45 GMT**

Response Header sent by Cloudflare:

> Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>
> CF-Cache-Status:MISS
>
> CF-RAY:xxxxxxxxxxxxx-XXX
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Type:image/gif
>
> Content-Length:12345
>
> Date:Wed, 12 Jul 2017 13:50:29 GMT
>
> Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> Server:cloudflare-nginx
>
> Vary:Accept-Encoding

As can be seen the 'Set-Cookie' header is not forwarded to my clients by Cloudflare.

Although this issue got resolved when I created a page rule and set Bypass Cache for the resource-url.

Can anyone guide me what am I missing or additional headers to send from my backend server so that 'Set-Cookie' is also forwarded through Cloudflare?